# Data sorting and grouping in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

Some one mistakenly inputted negative values to unique key column 
long back and now i have to group the data selecting max of ID as per category to extract report. ID column now have both positive and negative values.

Max(ID) function  is not working correctly with negative values.

```
    ID   Category
    45678    A
    234567   B
    -4578    A
    -45798    A
    -7890    C
    -8904    C
    -7654    C
```

Expected O/P is

```
ID   Category
45678    A
234567   B 
-8904    C
```

Comment: *Please* show your sql.

Comment: select max(id) from table_name group by Category. But the query fails for negative values.

Comment: Shouldn't A be -45798?

Comment: `max(id)` works perfectly fine for negative numbers. Did you study inequalities for negative numbers? Do you remember, from middle school, that -100 is GREATER than -900, not smaller as you seem to think? `max(id)` for `category = 'C'` is -7654. Or do you mean something else? Like "the minus sign should be ignored"? If that is the assignment, then `max(id)` is the wrong solution!

Comment: Actually before 2010 all datas has positive values. During migration from some other system they appended - before the positive values and loaded in new system (ie) Oracle database. So ID with largest negative values will have latest data before 2010 and id with positive values are created after 2010

Comment: As per the data i have -900 is greater than -100 :( As is is a sequence before 2010 and when migrated they just appended (-) to existing and did

Comment: Sounds like you have some serious data integrity issues.  If you cannot rely on a set of columns to determine the correct outcome ( date is null sometimes, etc.), how are we supposed to?

Comment: We suggested data clean up and since it includes massive data they are not willing to. It is data issue

Comment: So what you really want is the largest negative **unless** there is a positive number for that category also.

Comment: Both are positive values ex: 100 and 101 return latest positive (ie) 101 ....One positive and one negative  -100 and 90 return positive (ie) 90 .....Both negative -90 and -100 return most negative ie (-100) grouped by Category

Comment: I give up. You aren't being clear. You should seriously fix the ID properly which should be easy to do regardless of how "massive" it is.

Comment: Its Business call :( We proposed the same and they didn't agree for data fix. If data fix happens the requirement is pretty simple

Comment: Well, an ID is basically just something to identify a record uniquely which it does, no matter whether positive or negative. As a general rule: You should never change IDs. Here you want the ID to also work as a sortkey for the records, which it doesn't, because of the negative/postive issue. But you can still add a sortkey. For example as a computed column: `case when id < 0 then 10000000000 - id else 20000000000 + id end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "So ID with largest negative values will have latest data before 2010
>   and id with positive values are created after 2010"

That means in case there are positive IDs for a category you want the maximum (e.g. 45678 for category A) and otherwise the minimum (e.g. -8904 for category C). You can use Oracle's `KEEP FIRST/LAST` for this:

```
select 
  category, 
  max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by sign(id), abs(id))
from mytable
group by category
order by category;
```

This sorts your IDs by sign (negative before positive ones, so if there are positive ones you'd prefer these) and then by absolute amount (so you get the highest negative or positive as the last row, which is the one you pick with `KEEP LAST`).

Comment: Man its Amazing. You are a genius